# MySQL Union Operator not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, union

I usually find the answer to my questions here. If not, I know that is probably because I haven't looked deep enough. However this time none of the answers I looked through fit my needs. So here it goes:

I want to use MySQL server to build a report from two tables:

```
ID              Email                  ID     Date      Spent
-----------------------              ---------------------------
A123         a@test.com               A123      3.3.14     2.50
B102         b@test.com               A123      7.3.14     3.50
yum          yum@a.com                B102      4.4.14     7.00
(null)         (null)
```

I want to make a report in which for a given timestamp, eg. from 3.1.2014 to 3.31.14, I get a list of all the ID's of the system with the corresponding amount that they have sent, even if they didn't spend anything.

Therefore from the above tables, let's say we want to retrieve the month of March 2014 (from 3.1.2014 to 3.31.14), I would like to get:

```
ID          Spent
------------------
A123         6.00
B102         7.00
yum          NULL
```

I don't mind to have NULL or 0's for those users that didn't spend any money. So far I have gotten this:

```
SELECT ID,
   sum(Spent) AS Spent
FROM expenses
WHERE expenses.date >= '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
  AND expenses.date < '2014-03-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY expenses.ID
UNION
SELECT users.ID,
   NULL AS Spent
FROM users
WHERE users.ID NOT IN
 (SELECT expenses.ID
   FROM expenses
   WHERE expenses.date >= '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
   AND expenses.date < '2014-03-31 00:00:00'
 GROUP BY expenses.ID)
ORDER BY ID;
```

You can check the above code in [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/738ea6/1).

It works as expected, but in the real case of my database, the amount of rows in the result query is greater that the amount of unique rows in `users`.

I have checked that all the ID's in the `expenses` table are in the `users` tables, which is the case. I have tested with:

```
SELECT ID FROM expenses
  WHERE expenses.date >= '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
 AND expenses.date < '2014-03-31 00:00:00'
 AND ID NOT IN (SELECT users.ID FROM users);
```

and it returns an empty set, which is as expected.

I must be missing something, but I have no clue of what. Could someone please give some insights? I am pretty new to MySQL, and maybe there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: The most likely explanation for the behavior you observe is that there are rows in `expenses` with `ID` values that don't match any `ID` value in `users`. The first part of your query doesn't restrict the values of `ID` returned from `expenses`. One way to identify those `ID` values from expenses: **`SELECT e.ID FROM expenses e LEFT JOIN users u ON u.ID=e.ID WHERE u.ID IS NULL GROUP BY e.ID`**. See Gordon's answer for an example of a query that returns the specified resultset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `left outer join` rather than a `union`:

```
SELECT u.ID, sum(e.Spent) AS Spent
FROM users u left outer join
     expenses e
     on u.id = e.id and
        e.date >= '2014-03-01 00:00:00' and
        e.date < '2014-03-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY u.ID;
```

Note in the data you have in the SQL Fiddle, this will return four rows, because of the `NULL` valued row in `users`.

Comment: +1. a `LEFT JOIN` is the way to go. Adding a **`WHERE users.ID IS NOT NULL`** would eliminate that "extra" NULL row from `users`. An easy way to replace a NULL from the SUM aggregate with a zero is to wrap it in a `IFNULL()` function...  **`IFNULL(sum(e.Spent),0)`**

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, really appreciated. @spencer7593 `SELECT e.ID FROM expenses e LEFT JOIN users u ON u.ID=e.ID WHERE u.ID IS NULL GROUP BY e.ID` worked like charm to identify Id's that where on e.ID and were not on u.ID. I thought it u.ID had all the Id's and it turned out that not....                                               @gordon-linoff Thanks a lot, I am running the query now, but I have to say it is significantly slower than my union. Keep in mind that expenses.ID has 4K records and users.id has 100K. Thank you once more!

Comment: @tokenizer_fsj: That query uses an "anti-join" pattern, effective (and usually the most efficient query pattern) for identifying rows that don't have a match, essentially the inverse of the rows returned by Gordon's query above. To "fix" your original query, you'd add an INNER JOIN to the `users` table in the top part of your query. The `LEFT JOIN` (as demonstrated in Gordon's answer, is a (usually) more efficient pattern to get the "non-matching" rows. Suitable indexes should markedly improve performance of the JOIN operation.

Comment: A covering index **`... ON expenses (id, date, spent)`** will likely improve performance. (Likely there's already an index `on users(id)` . It strikes me a bit odd that the date range includes only the first 30 days of March, and not the whole month. (Nothing wrong with getting the first thirty days, it's just odd.) To get the whole month, we'd typically use something like **`e.date >= '2014-03-01' AND e.date < '2014-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`**.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a join of two tables (Users and Expenses) to get the same result (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/738ea6/5). This will be much faster and an understandable query.

```
SELECT expenses.ID,
   sum(Spent) AS Spent
FROM expenses, users 
WHERE expenses.date >= '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
  AND expenses.date < '2014-03-31 00:00:00'
  AND users.ID = expenses.ID
GROUP BY expenses.ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: You'd need an outer join to return rows from `users` that don't have any matching rows in `expenses`.

Answer (score 0):

Group by in second query?

```
    SELECT ID,
   sum(Spent) AS Spent
FROM expenses
WHERE expenses.date >= '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
  AND expenses.date < '2014-03-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY expenses.ID
UNION
SELECT users.ID,
   NULL AS Spent
FROM users
WHERE users.ID NOT IN
 (SELECT expenses.ID
   FROM expenses
   WHERE expenses.date >= '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
   AND expenses.date < '2014-03-31 00:00:00'
 GROUP BY expenses.ID)
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```